# Perl MySQL error - please debug

Tags: mysql, perl

> INSERT INTO donal
>   (dateTime,1_1_windSpeed,1_2_windDirection,1_3_solarRadiance,1_4_tempera
>   ture,1_5_RH,2_1_apt11_8_plug,2_2_apt11_6_plug,2_3_apt11_1_plug,2_4_apt11_3_plug,
>   2_5_rainGuage,3_1_apt1_3_light,3_2_apt1_9_light,3_3_apt1_6_light,3_4_apt11_3_plu
>   g,3_5_apt11_3_light,3_6_apt11_6_light,3_7_apt12_6_light,3_8_apt11_8_light,4_1_ap
>   t8_6_light,4_2_apt8_7_light,4_3_apt7_6_light,4_4_apt7_9_light,4_5_apt_3_light,4_
>   6_apt7_1_light,4_7_apt8_6_plug,4_8_apt8_7_plug,5_1_apt7_3_plug,5_2_apt7_9_plug,5
>   _3_apt7_1_plug,5_4_apt7_6_plug,5_5_apt1_9_plug,5_6_apt1_6_plug,5_7_apt1_3_plug,5
>   _8_apt12_6_plug,6_1_DHW_DistHeating,6_2_AHUwestEnd,6_3_AHUeastEnd,6_4_DHWpreHeat ,6_5_solar20mm,6_6_solar30mm,6_7_WBldDistHeating)
>   VALUES(2012-05-29T09:50:00,431
>   .956,967.042,-5.27581,-0.489368,8.74281,9,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,14,0,0,10,0,0,
>   0,8,0,9,0,9,8,6,8,8,0,3,40,83,6,0,1,1)DBD::mysql::db do failed: You
>   have an erro r in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server ver sion for the right syntax to use near
>   ':50:00,431.956,967.042,-5.27581,-0.489368
>   ,8.74281,9,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,14,0' at line 1 at monitor.pl line
>   187,  line 1. DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual  that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near
>   ':50:00,431.956,967.042,-5.27581,-0.489368,8.74281,9,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,14, 0' at line 1 at monitor.pl line 187,  line 1. Terminating on
>   signal SIGINT(2)

Greetings,

I keep getting the above MySQL error. I simply can't get to the bottom of it.

I thought I'd ask the community.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: why, it's simple

Comment: You know we don't all use MySQL on a daily basis...

Comment: Got it working now folks. Just had to quote the dateTime field. And as for the negativity... Well...

Comment: @Eamorr: the negativity would go if you at least formatted the code properly.

Comment: What code? All I see is a query.

Answer (score 3):

Quote the constants in your `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You are not quoting your values before using them in your query. `2012-05-29T09:50:00` is not a valid SQL literal, and needs to be in quotes, although you are apparently inserting a timestamp into a column named `1_1_windSpeed`, which does not make much sense; my guess is you have forgotten or misplaced a column somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have a column for dateTime... I've edited the OP. Also, thank you for your observation about quotes.